# Gnome 3 extensions don't work reliably

Tags: linux, gnome, gnome3

I'm using opensuse with GNOME 3. Every time I log in, some of the extensions don't work anymore. Switching the extension ON/OFF doesn't have any effect. I have to log out and log on again several times to make it work.

For example I have Frippery Move Clock to move the clock to the right, and when I log in sometimes it works correctly and sometimes the clock is still in the middle. Some other examples being Better Volume Indicator, AlternateTab, Touchpad Indicator...

Why is that and how to fix it?